# Why does the router link not work the first time?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, quasar

I have a grpc application, there is authorization. When you start a project, you must be logged in. I decided to add  under the login button if you are not registered. But the router does not work. Only at the entrance, go to the registration page. Please help to understand what is the mistake? Why is  seemingly blocked?

routes.js

```
  const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: () => import("layouts/MainLayout"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: () => import("pages/Index"),
        meta: { requireAuth: true }
      },

      {
        path: "/logs",
        component: () => import("pages/Logs"),
        meta: { requireAuth: true, admin: true }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    component: () => import("layouts/AuthLayout"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/welcome",
        component: () => import("pages/Auth"),
        meta: { guest: true }
      },
      {
        path: "/register",
        component: () => import("pages/Register"),
        meta: { guest: true }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I tried many things, like in Auth.vue:

```
  <q-item to='/register'>Sign Up</q-item> 
  <router-link tag="a" :to="{path:'/register'}" replace>Go</router-link>
  <span @click="callSomeFunc()">Register</span>
  ...
  methods: {
    callSomeFunc() {
    this.$router.push({ path: "/register" });
  }
```

My router-view in App.vue

[for more information github repo](https://github.com/tavitamenashe01/grpc-app/tree/master/client/src)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicate routes in your config - the path `/` is used on 2 routes. You should fix this.

To prevent unauthorized users to see your protected pages you can add a global navigation guard to your router through the `beforeEach` hook:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: () => import("layouts/MainLayout"),
    meta: { requireAuth: true },
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: () => import("pages/Index"),
      },

      {
        path: "logs",
        component: () => import("pages/Logs"),
        meta: { admin: true }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    component: () => import("layouts/AuthLayout"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: () => import("pages/Auth"),
      },
      {
        path: "/register",
        component: () => import("pages/Register"),
      }
    ]
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) =>
{
  if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requireAuth))
  {
    if (userNotLogged) next('/login');
    else next();
  }
  else next();
});


export default router;
```

You may also consider reading a more verbose tutorial, e.g. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vue-js-authentication-and-route-handling-using-vue-router

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t quite understand and i already tried to convert routes, like this:


`const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
     component: () => import("pages/Auth"),
    meta: { guest: true }
    },
  ]
})
`

And 
`export default router`

Comment: I am very grateful for your help but it still not working, i think probably due to the fact that the main router / index.js already has a hook beforeEach. I tried to connect them, but without result (

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it! 
My mistake was in that i tried to write everything in on beforeEach hook... 
And i did like this: 
`Router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => 
  await store.restored;
  if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requireAuth)) {
    if (!store.state.auth.status && to.path !== "/welcome") next("/welcome");
    else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
`

Very happy and grateful :D